# python: get value of nested dictionary in generic way

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making simple use case of my problem, here its is:

```
dic =  {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}}
```

Now i want to have a method which operates on this dictionary, fetch values based on the key.

```
def get_value(dic, key):
     return dic[key]
```

At different places this generic method will be called to fetch the values.

`get_value(dic, 'a')` will work.

Is it be possible to get the value `2 (dic['b']['c'])` in more generic way.

Comment: You meant `dic['b']['c']`, not `dic['a']['b']`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using unbound method [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (or `dict.__getitem__`) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> # from functools import reduce  # Python 3.x only
>>> reduce(dict.get, ['b', 'c'], {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}})
2

>>> reduce(lambda d, key: d[key], ['b', 'c'], {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}})
2
```

**UPDATE**

If you use `dict.get` and try to access non-existing key, it could hide `KeyError` by returning `None`:

```
>>> reduce(dict.get, ['x', 'c'], OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'NoneType'
```

To prevent that, use `dict.__getitem__`:

```
>>> reduce(dict.__getitem__, ['x', 'c'], OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'x'
```